# npoi 'Sheet' type or namespace could not be found

Tags: c#, .net, excel, npoi

This seems like a super simple issue to resolve.  The type or namespace 'Sheet' is simply not there, so I get the red underline with the above message.

I have included:

```
using NPOI.HSSF.UserModel;
using NPOI.HPSF;
using NPOI.POIFS.FileSystem;
using NPOI.SS.UserModel;//(i think it should be in here)
```

Code that has error:

```
HSSFWorkbook hssfworkbook;
hssfworkbook = new HSSFWorkbook();

Sheet sheet1 = hssfworkbook.CreateSheet("Sheet1");  //this causes the error
```

Oh and further down, same error here.  'Row' not defined.

```
Row row = sheet1.CreateRow(i);
```

Using MS Visual Studio 2013. (C#)
Thanks.

Comment: If it did work before, try to clean and rebuild your project

Comment: It is just ISheet, IRow.

Answer (score 0):

you need to typecast the `ISheet` interface returned by the `CreateSheet` method to `HSSFSheet`.  Namespace should be `NPOI.SS.UserModel`:

```
HSSFWorkbook hssfworkbook= new HSSFWorkbook ();
HSSFSheet sheet1 = (HSSFSheet)hssfworkbook.CreateSheet("Sheet1");
var row = sheet1.CreateRow(0);
```